# Liking multiple properties with one Like button

Tags: facebook-like

My company owns several magazines and we want to put one LIKE button on our corporate site to like all of our magazines. Is there a way to do this? I have been searching around and cant find a solution.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure this can't be done as a means of security.
I may click like on your "Pie of the Month" magazine, but if you control the button, you may have me like "Pie of the Month." "Womens Shoes." and "Girls Gone Crazy." I believe the reason is obvious why facebook won't allow this. 
Instead try doing a like button for your corporations entire collection of magazines or "Gamer Magazines by xxxxxx."

This should help solve the problem without asking facebook to rewrite the entire API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I thought the same thing and do not like the idea but I am just trying to do what the bosses ask.